# Flutter Firebase if document doesn't exist

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, where-clause

I just want to say if the document exists setState(the first one) else setState(the second one). I'm new in flutter so please don't hate :)

Thanks for helping!

```
   Future<String> TerminBesetztOderFrei(String Friseur, String Tag, String Uhrzeit) async {
    await Firestore.instance.collection("$Friseur/1/$Tag/1/$Uhrzeit")
        .getDocuments()
        .then((querySnapshot) {
      querySnapshot.documents.forEach((result) {
        print(result.exists);
        setState(() {
          terminText = "Termin nicht verfügbar!";
          terminTextFarbe = Colors.red;
          buttonVisible = false;
        });
      });
    });
    setState(() {
      if(nameController.text != "" && telController.text != "") {
        terminText = "Termin verfügbar!";
        terminTextFarbe = Colors.green;
        buttonVisible = true;
      } else {
        terminText = "Termin verfügbar! Bitte Name und Telefon eingeben!";
        terminTextFarbe = Colors.green;
        buttonVisible = false;
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: I think in the query snapshots you will get the documents and they will all exist. :) if the document doesn't exist, then it won't be included in the querysnapshot. if you have any specific id of the document, then you can check if it exists or not.

Comment: In the folder is only one or no document. And if I add a new document with flutter the document id is always a random ID. Is there a way to set the document ID by myself?

Comment: Yes. For that you need to create a document reference with your custom id and use this document reference to set the data

Comment: Read the code under this post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the document Id:

```
  final docSnapshot = await Firestore.instance
    .collection("$Friseur/1/$Tag/1/$Uhrzeit")
    .document(${doc_id_here})
    .get();

    if(docSnapshot.exists) {
      setState(...)
    }
    else {
      setState(...)
    }
```

If you haven't

```
  final querySnapshot = await Firestore.instance
    .collection("$Friseur/1/$Tag/1/$Uhrzeit")
    .getDocuments();

    if(querySnapshot.documents.isNotEmpty) {
      setState(...)
    }
```

Comment: The Document is always random... Is there a way without knowing the doc. There ist always just one doc.